# Stop Propagation on different element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to determine how to temporarily disable click events (or propagation?) from a different element. 
So when you click on mousedown on  an event on a specific element, another elements click event is no longer fired.

```
Simplified Example:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="World">World</div>
<div id="Hello">Hello</div>

    <script>
    $(document).mousedown(function (e){
        if( $('.there').length ){
            $('.there').remove();
            console.log('removed there');
            //here is where I would need the '#World' click event to not fire
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click','#World',function(){
        console.log('World');
    });
    $(document).on('click','#Hello',function(){
        console.log('Hello');
        $(this).append('<div class="there">there</div>');
        console.log('added there');
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An event is fired by an element... Or collection of elements you specifie.
**And all their childrens.**

[Events happen is this order](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/Wowmba?editors=1111):

1. mousedown
2. mouseup
3. click

*«when you click on mousedown on an event on a specific element»*
    really would need another way to explain it...

But I think I answered.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/Wowmba?editors=1111):

```
$(document).on("mousedown",function(){
    console.log("mousedown");
});

$(document).on("click",function(){
    console.log("click");
});

$(document).on("mouseup",function(){
    console.log("mouseup");
});

//----

$(document).find("#main").on("mousedown click mouseup",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("NOTHING....");
});

$(document).find("#okay input").on("mousedown click mouseup",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Just the OKAY");
});
```

**JUST CLICK everywhere** while checking console.

An attentive eye will see how to disable inheritance.
And how it "bubbles".

Answer (score 0):

I've seen developers remove the events from the second element temporarily, and then add them back when necessary, but I find the best method for temporarily disabling a specific event is to add code to the event's handler that checks for some kind of status variable or class. I feel like I worded that poorly so here's a quick example:

```
var buttonsToDisable = $('.mybuttons'),
    disablerButton = $('#disabler');

buttonsToDisable.on('click',function(e) {
    var ele = $(this);
    if(!ele.is('.disable-click')) {
        // some event handler logic here
    };
});

// Toggle click-events on all buttons with the .mybuttons class when clicked
disablerButton.on('click',function(e) {
    if(!buttonsToDisable.is('.disable-click')) {
        buttonsToDisable.addClass('disable-click');
    } else {
        buttonsToDisable.removeClass('disable-click');
    };
});
```

If you also wanted to stop the propagation of the `mybuttons` events, then just add an `else` to that `if` statement and in there call the event's `stopPropagation()` function.

Answer (score 0):

As #World is children of parent, then if you click on #World first its click event will be fired, then parent (div,body etc), then html.

If you will stop propagation on #World,click event for parents event will not fire even for a single time.

I think you need to check if there is lenth of .there is available when clicking on #World. i.e.

```
$(document).on('click','#World',function(){
    if ( $('.there').length ) {
        return; // or return false;
    }

    else {
        //code you want to execute
        console.log('World');
    }
});
```